# what is the database schema for storing nested Json Objects?

Tags: mysql, json, oracle, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I am getting records for a service contains nested json objects as shown below.
I am able catch the result. I need to store this result in DB. here I facing problem in storing these result in db.

```
[
name:"",
geocode: {
latitude: "45.4168953"
longitude: "-75.6927428"
         },
website: {
title: ""
scope: ""
          },
promotion: {
status:true
           },
.....
.....
.....
]
```

what might be the database schema for storing this nested JSON Oject.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please help, I have similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49881817/does-handling-nested-object-using-json-stringify-parse-cause-performance-issue

Answer (score 1):

Well ,if you are restricted to mysql database , it is simple to new a table named geocode , it has three keys:id  ,latitude  ,longitude ,then ,in your main table, you have a key named geocode ,whose value is a geocode which points to one row in geocode.It is just a simple one-to-many mapping. So does other composite keys like website , promotion and so on.But according to what I know , NoSQL databases ,such as mongoDB ,has a very good support for JSON object and can absolute meet your requirement.

Comment: Can you help me on this ? :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49881817/does-handling-nested-object-using-json-stringify-parse-cause-performance-issue